# gstreamer fallbacksrc plugin can not link glimagesink

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I want to use the gstreamer plugin **fallbacksrc** on linux.

##### fallbacksrc (with ximagesink) -> OK

```
gst-launch-1.0 fallbacksrc \
  uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm \
  fallback-uri=file:///path/to/some/jpg \
  ! videoconvert \
  ! ximagesink
```

It works as expected.

##### fallbacksrc (with glimagesink) -> NG

```
gst-launch-1.0 fallbacksrc \
  uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm \
  fallback-uri=file:///path/to/some/jpg \
  ! videoconvert \
  ! glimagesink
```

It does not work.

- error message

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Noformat', utils/fallbackswitch/src/fallbacksrc/imp.rs:1897:36
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
```

It seems pad linking(capability) problem. But even if I inserted capsfilter `video/x-raw` before videoconvert, same error happens.

How to use fallbacksrc with glimagesink ?

#### Environment

- gstreamer version

  1.22 (installed by [archlinux package repo](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gstreamer/))
- gst-plugins-rs

  0.9.7 (installed by [archlinux user package repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gst-plugins-rs))

Answer (score 0):

It should fixed with this commit: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/commit/722dba12037febc4f6886bbf8d060ffbd920076f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).